# Let's stop these graphics questions

Tags: feature-request, tags

I just saw we still have a ["graphics"](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) tag.

Seems untidy since it could be applied to literally every question we have. Whether or not a question is tagged with it appears to be completely random.

Can we - I believe the technical term is - "burninate" it?

---

***bump*** It looks like we're agreed that a graphics Q&A is no place for graphics questions, how do we begin stamping them out?

I saw a mention of an obstacle being questions *only* tagged "graphics", which may need to be manually re-tagged. If this is the case, can someone post some magic search link that lists such questions? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics lists *all* graphics questions, but I can't see a way to see questions *only* tagged with "graphics".

Comment: +1 for the Q title alone :) But yes, I agree.

Comment: I am for this as well but if we are going to do it we need to make an to the 20 questions that have this tag.

Comment: Oh sure, kill it when I'm 1 tick away from getting a badge for it :) Actually  agree.. it's kind of a stupid tag.

Comment: Looks like someone's already made a magic search: https://data.stackexchange.com/graphicdesign/query/232959/find-posts-where-x-is-the-only-tag :) Not too many according to that query.

Answer (score 2):

Can we kill [art](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/art) too, while we are at it (for the same reasons)?

Comment: I'd disagree, 90%+ of our questions are about design not art, but we do welcome visual arts questions, so I think it has a purpose. Looking at the tagged questions, some are mistagged but most are actually questions about art and not design.

Comment: what if we refined this one to 'fine-art'? That might give it a bit more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Does it fit as a synonym of [images](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images)?

On first thought that seems like the best thing to do with it to me.

Comment: I'm tempted to post a second Q titled "No more images" asking to kill that tag too...

Comment: @user568458 that idea [has been proposed before](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2456/is-there-any-use-to-the-images-tag) and the concensus was to keep it (grmbl).